# Jquery Code to validate code

Tags: jquery

Please i need this code to check if the access key is correct or not and when the person put wrong key more than 3 times it will show expired or take to another page.

I don't know what am doing wrong since i can't code the error attempt but still without that is not working can someone help me?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var acc = 7829;
    var AccessKey = $('#AccessKey').val();

    $("#accessBTN").click(function(){
        if(AccessKey == acc){

        $('#TokenVf').attr("style", "display:none");
        $('#infotf').text("Your access is granted to click continue to proceed to payment.");
        $('#statustf').html("<font color='green'>Verified Access</font>");
        $("#TokenGO").toggle(1000);

        }
        else{
        $('#statustf').html("<font color='red'>Error</font>");  
        $('#infotf').html("<font color='red'>Please correct your access code and try again</font>");
        $('#AccessKey').addClass('surname text error');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is HTML

```
<div id="statustf"></div><br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var check = 0;

  $("#accessBTN").click(function() {
    var acc = 7829;
    var AccessKey = $('#AccessKey').val();
    //alert(AccessKey+acc)
    if (AccessKey == acc && check < 3) {

      $('#TokenVf').attr("style", "display:none");
      $('#infotf').text("Your access is granted to click continue to proceed to payment.");
      $('#statustf').html("<font color='green'>Verified Access</font>");
      $("#TokenGO").toggle(1000);

    } else {
      $('#statustf').html("<font color='red'>Error</font>");
      $('#infotf').html("<font color='red'>Please correct your access code and try again</font>");
      $('#AccessKey').addClass('surname text error');
      check++
    }
    if (check > 3) {
      alert("'expired'")
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="AccessKey" />
<button id="accessBTN">access</button>
<div id="statustf"></div>
<br/>
```

Comment: NICE WORK HERE @sharma sk

Answer (score 1):

The `var AccessKey = $('#AccessKey').val();` is being executed right after the page loads, not when you click on the button. Put it inside the `$("#accessBTN").click(function(){` block so it will actually check the password each time the click is triggered from the access button. In the original code the input value was only checked on page load and wasn't updated later on..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var acc = 7829;        

    $("#accessBTN").click(function(){
        var AccessKey = $('#AccessKey').val(); //<-- here
        if(AccessKey == acc){

            $('#TokenVf').attr("style", "display:none");
            $('#infotf').text("Your access is granted to click continue to proceed to payment.");
            $('#statustf').html("<font color='green'>Verified Access</font>");
            $("#TokenGO").toggle(1000);

        } else {
            $('#statustf').html("<font color='red'>Error</font>");  
            $('#infotf').html("<font color='red'>Please correct your access code and try again</font>");
            $('#AccessKey').addClass('surname text error');
        }
    });
});
```